# Grails - How to fetch one-many relationship using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a two domain classes, User and Item as given below

```
class User {
    String username;    
    static hasMany = [wishList: Item]
}

class Item {
    String heading;
    static belongsTo = [owner: User]
}
```

Am trying to trying to display both(user and his wishList) details together in page. Now if i user "JOIN"(as shown below), i get duplicate user rows

```
def users = criteria.list(offset:0, max:10) {
    fetchMode("wishList", org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN)
}
```

If i use "SELECT", as below. There (n+1) sql queries happening.

```
def users = criteria.list(offset:0, max:10) {
    fetchMode("wishList", org.hibernate.FetchMode.SELECT)
}
```

Whats the best way(in terms of performance) to display this data.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch `wishList` for a particular `user` (providing the user id) or for all the users?

Comment: Am trying fetch wishList for all users

Comment: In that case lazy fetching (N+1) will be a better approach because if you use `FetchMode` `JOIN` or use the DSL way of fetching the association then all the associations (`wishList`) will be eagerly fetched for all the users. If there are 1000 users with 1000 wishlists each, then it will be performance hit. On the other hand, fetching it lazily, will give you wishList for that particular user which is selected. If no of users and corresponding `wishList` is small then I would have suggested `FetchMode JOIN`. Profile your use case in both scenarios and see how it performs.

Comment: But other than that, do we have a third option? Which would fetch all userList, with wishList populated inside user, in one single database hit(single query). I just want to make sure that, there is no third option available.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding something. Your first approach using JOIN should bring back what you want, eagerly, right? Yes there users will be duplicate user entries but that should not be a problem for you. Now why are we thinking of a third option?

Comment: Duplication is a problem. I use pagination, so once i get the batch of data(lets say 10 Users) using join, after removing duplicates, the batch would contain only two Users. That's why i am looking for a third option(if there is any), that fetches all data(including wishList), but without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, the best way to go is using join

```
def users = criteria.list(offset:0, max:10) {
    fetchMode("wishList", org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN)
}
```

Yes, there will be duplicate rows, but that can be easily removed, using unique method `users.unique()`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent duplicate row using following implementation:

```
def users = criteria.list(offset:0, max:10) {
    fetchMode "wishList", FetchMode.JOIN
    resultTransformer Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
}
```